# How to view the Suggsetions sorted in the Database for the last three months?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a New ASP.NET Developer and I am trying to develop a simple suggestion box system. I have the following part of my database desing:

> User Table: Username, Name, DivisionCode... etc
>
> Division Table: SapCode, Division
>
> SuggestionLog Table: ID, Title, Description, submittedDate, Username

***(The first attribute is the primary key in each table and the attribute (submittedDate) is of DateTime data type)***

Now, I need to develop a table that shows suggestions for the last three months. I already developed a query that shows the Employee Name, Username, Division, Suggestion Title, Suggestion Description. All what I want now is to show the Month. For example, to show the suggestions for the last three months, the Month column should show: Jan-2012, Dec-2011, Nov-2011 **So how to do that?**

My current SQL query:

```
SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.Type, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, 
                      dbo.employee.Name, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsType ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.TypeID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.ID
```

The desired output is to display:

**Employee Name, Username, Division, SuggestionTitle, SuggstionDescription, SuggestionType Month(submissionDate)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted you query so it would fit on the page without scrolling.

Hopefully this provides what you need. It uses [`DATENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) to get the month and year parts from the current date and [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to do the "three months ago" calculation.
Note that `DATEPART` doesn't behave as you might expect - it counts the number of period-end boundaries (in this case months) - hence the condition is

```
...WHERE DATEDIFF(month,SafetySuggestionsLog.submittedDate,getdate()) < 3
```

because the last three months have two month-end boundaries between them.

I also added an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, 
           dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, 
           dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.Type, 
           dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, 
           dbo.employee.Name, 
           dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut,
           left(datename(month,SafetySuggestionsLog.submittedDate),3) 
            + '-' 
            + datename(year,SafetySuggestionsLog.submittedDate) AS SubmittedMonth
FROM         dbo.Divisions 
INNER JOIN   dbo.employee 
ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode 
INNER JOIN   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog 
ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username 
INNER JOIN   dbo.SafetySuggestionsType 
ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.TypeID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(month,SafetySuggestionsLog.submittedDate,getdate()) < 3
ORDER BY SafetySuggestionsLog.submittedDate DESC
```

It might also be worth noting that you don't have to fully qualify the name of all the columns in the query - it's valid SQL to alias the input tables like so:

```
...INNER JOIN   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog AS log
```

You can then refer to column names by alias in the query - e.g.

```
log.Username
```

instead of

```
dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username
```

which makes it a bit easier to read.

Comment: thank you very much. I really appreciate your help and explanation. You really helped me and I learned something from you.